# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, disnake

Делаю Discord бота для обработки заказов.

В настоящее время я работаю над функцией принятия заказов. Когда заказчик заполняет через бота форму о своих потребностях, его сообщение (в виде `embed`) автоматически отправляется в специальный канал, который доступен только приемщикам. Если кто-то из приемщиков готов взять заказ, он нажимает кнопку "принять". После этого создается отдельный канал в предварительно созданной категории, который доступен только заказчику и приемщику. Кроме того, сообщение, под которым находилась кнопка, должно обновиться и добавить информацию о приемщике, который принял заказ, внизу текста.

Ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in view <takeOrder timeout=180.0 children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.success: 3> url=None disabled=False label='Принять' emoji=None row=None>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\ui\view.py", line 385, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\nikit\PycharmProjects\DiscordBots\Bot\DSBot.py", line 129, in take_order_button
    await interaction.guild.create_text_channel(f"channel", category=category, overwrites=permissions)
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\guild.py", line 1357, in create_text_channel
    data = await self._create_channel(
  File "C:\Users\nikit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\guild.py", line 1197, in _create_channel
    payload = {"allow": allow.value, "deny": deny.value, "id": target.id}
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Код кнопки "принять":

```
class takeOrder(disnake.ui.View):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @disnake.ui.button(label="Принять", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def take_order_button(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        #guild = interaction.guild
        category = disnake.utils.get(interaction.guild.categories, id=1159115812586668144)

        permissions = {
            interaction.guild.default_role: disnake.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False, view_channel=False),
            interaction.author: disnake.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True, view_channel=True),
            slovar['client']: disnake.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True, view_channel=True)
        }

        slovar['var'] = 1
        slovar['executor_name'] = interaction.author.name
        slovar['executor_avatar'] = interaction.author.avatar

        await interaction.guild.create_text_channel(f"channel", category=category, overwrites=permissions)

    def to_components(self):
        return super().to_components()
```

Код `embed` сообщения, которое должно быть отредактировано:

```
class donationButton(disnake.ui.View):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # self.add_item(disnake.ui.Button(label="Pay", url="https://www.donationalerts.com/"))

    @disnake.ui.button(label="Pay", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple)#, url="https://www.donationalerts.com/r/skylightproduction")
    async def pay_button(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        order_channel = bot.get_channel(1130521980936921200)

        color = disnake.Color.default()
        if slovar["service_type"] == "Model":
            color = disnake.Color.brand_red()
        elif slovar["service_type"] == "Python code":
            color = disnake.Color.magenta()

        oreder_embed = disnake.Embed(title='Новый заказ:', color=color)
        oreder_embed.add_field(name=f'Код заказа: {slovar["service_code"]}\nДата оформления: {slovar["sending_time"]}\nИмя заказчика: {slovar["client"]}\nТип заказа: {slovar["service_type"]}\nСсылка на экземплы: {slovar["service_images"]}',value="")

        if slovar["totem_variant"] is not None:
            oreder_embed.add_field(name='Добавление тотема в игру:', value=slovar["totem_variant"])

        oreder_embed.add_field(name="Описание:", value=slovar["service_description"], inline=False)

        if slovar["mail"] is not None or slovar["vk"] is not None or slovar["telegram"]:
            oreder_embed.add_field(name="Доп. контакты связи:", value="", inline=False)
            if slovar["vk"] is not None:
                oreder_embed.add_field(name=f'VK: {slovar["vk"]}', value="", inline=False)
            if slovar["mail"] is not None:
                oreder_embed.add_field(name=f'Mail: {slovar["mail"]}', value="", inline=False)
            if slovar["telegram"] is not None:
                oreder_embed.add_field(name=f'Telegram: {slovar["telegram"]}', value="", inline=False)

        if not interaction.author.avatar:
            oreder_embed.set_author(name=interaction.author.display_name)
        else:
            oreder_embed.set_author(name=interaction.author.display_name, icon_url=interaction.author.avatar.url)

        message = await order_channel.send(embed=oreder_embed, view=takeOrder())
        if slovar['var'] == 1:
            oreder_embed.set_footer(
                text = f"**Заказ принял {slovar['executor_name']}**",
                icon_url = slovar['executor_avatar']
            )

            await message.edit(embed=oreder_embed)

        await interaction.send("Ссылка для оплаты: https://www.donationalerts.com/", ephemeral=True)

    def to_components(self):
        return super().to_components()
```

Comment: [How to fix attributeerror: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' in Python?](https://stacktuts.com/how-to-fix-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-items-in-python)